# How do I "Install" my application?

Tags: linux, windows

This is mostly a linux question, but I'd be interested in the windows answer as well.

I wrote a bash script, I know I can put it in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` and I can run it on my path, but the operating system (and by that I guess I mean apt-get) doesn't know it's there.

Is there a way to make it so that I can manage it with apt-get? What's the process for getting my application on the main repos so that other people can install it?

On the Windows side : How do I get my program to show up in the list of currently installed programs?

Comment: What have you looked for? Searching for "create .deb package" and "create .msi package" will give you plenty of results, many of them free. What are you stuck over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Is there a way to make it so that I can manage it with apt-get?**

Yes, most distros publish guides for doing this.

It's too long to summarise here.

http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html

---

> **What's the process for getting my application on the main repos**

That is covered in the link above. This piece is short enough to include here

> There are a number of paths that a package can take to enter Ubuntu. In most cases, going through Debian first can be the best path. This way ensures that your package will reach the largest number of users as it will be available in not just Debian and Ubuntu but all of their derivatives as well. Here are some useful links for submitting new packages to Debian:
>
> Debian Mentors FAQ - debian-mentors is for the mentoring of new and prospective Debian Developers. It is where you can find a sponsor to upload your package to the archive.
>
> Work-Needing and Prospective Packages - Information on how to file “Intent to Package” and “Request for Package” bugs as well as list of open ITPs and RFPs.
>
> Debian Developer’s Reference, 5.1. New packages - The entire document is invaluable for both Ubuntu and Debian packagers. This section documents processes for submitting new packages.
>
> In some cases, it might make sense to go directly into Ubuntu first. For instance, Debian might be in a freeze making it unlikely that your package will make it into Ubuntu in time for the next release. This process is documented on the “New Packages” section of the Ubuntu wiki.

You can of course start by setting up your own repo that interested people can make use of.

---

> **On the Windows side**

I suggest making that a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

- You can first put it on GitHub or similar and see how popular it gets.
- You can provide a `.deb` that people can use directly (`dpkg -i ...` or just double-click in their file manager), no need to go through the official repos. And you can also provide a `.rpm` for the RedHat-flavored distros.
- If the package becomes popular, you can setup a [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#Package_Archives) that the interested Ubuntu users will add to their software sources.
- Putting something on the official repos requires testing and maintenance manpower, so your package has to become really popular before this happens.

PS: between something that works on your computer and somethings that works on most people's computers, there can be a huge gap. Which is where the GitHub stage proves useful.

Comment: I like this answer, and the project is actually on GitHub already, but I've accepted the other answer since it more specifically answered what was asked.